# OpsHub License Exception: com.opshub.license.exception.LicenseNotExistException

Tags: opshub

I am getting an exception when using OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility (Trial Version) when trying to Migrate from TFS to VSTS .

I have put in the key that was emailed to me in the second step. This error was received after the validation completion. Here is the StackTrace from OpsHub.log

---

```
 (com.opshub.JSON.QuartzIntializationServlet) - Unexpected error ocurred during context initialization.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.opshub.license.install.LicenseInstaller.installLicense(LicenseInstaller.java:77)
    at com.opshub.JSON.QuartzIntializationServlet.registerLicFile(QuartzIntializationServlet.java:369)
    at com.opshub.JSON.QuartzIntializationServlet.installLicenses(QuartzIntializationServlet.java:345)
```

---

----------Few lines below was the following error------------

```
(com.opshub.eai.config.service.ConfigServiceImpl) - Trial license is not installed
com.opshub.license.exception.LicenseNotExistException: Trial license is not installed
    at com.opshub.license.verify.LicenseVerifier.validateTrialLicense(LicenseVerifier.java:440)
    at com.opshub.license.verify.LicenseVerifier.validateIntegrationTerms(LicenseVerifier.java:238)
    at com.opshub.license.verify.LicenseVerifier.verify(LicenseVerifier.java:168)
```

---

Any help would be appreciated . TIA

Comment: Hi, please get in touch with support@opshub.com, we'll send you a license.

Comment: Hi Abhi, alternatively you can also download a newer patch from the VS Gallery page. (The version 2.5.0.001 has the fix to the aforementioned issue)

Comment: The new version of the program resolved this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments , the newer version of  OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you can migrate TFS to VSTS through TFS Data Import Service for Visual Studio.

More information, you can refer to this blog: [Import your TFS Database into Visual Studio Team Services](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/11/16/import-your-tfs-database-into-visual-studio-team-services/) and the tool and guide can be download from here: [Team Foundation Server to Visual Studio Team Services Migration Guide and Database Import Tooling](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54274).